# How to replace all comma with spaces to comma only in a String?

Tags: java, regex, string

What I have is:

```
"atul ,   singh Java   ,  computer science and engineering     ,    Data structures &   algorithms"
```

What i want is:

```
"atul,singh Java,computer science and engineering,Data structures &   algorithms"
```

Can any one please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\s*,\s*
```

**In java:**

```
your_string= your_string.replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", ",");
```

**Explanation:**

- `\s*` - Match a string of characters that are all "whitespace" (spaces,tabs,line breaks,etc.)
- `,` - Match the character ","

Comment: This is correct, _but_, since it's fairly clear that the OP doesn't know about regular expressions, some explanation would go a long way.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take your input.

Use `.split("\\s+,\\s+")` to take out the commas and surrounding whitespacing. If you have no spaces on both sides of the commas, replace the `+`"s with `*`

Join that string array back together with commas and no spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String a= " atul ,  singh Java , computer science and engineering , Data structures & algorithms ";
String b[]= a.split(",");
String c = "";
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
  c+=b[i].trim()+",";
}
System.out.println(c.substring(0,c.length()-1));
}
```

Comment: what happens if there are tabs or several spaces surrounding the comma?